# Creating a C# service to monitor changes in infinite loop

Tags: c#, windows-services

My goal is to see if there are any changes between Time1 and Time2. If there ARE changes, I need to send an email and skip the rest of the checks before another change occurs within another time interval.

This is my first time creating a service, so this is what I did:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime lastUpdate = new DateTime();
        lastUpdate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
        DateTime curTime = new DateTime();


        bool infLoop = true;
        while (infLoop)
        {                
            curTime = DateTime.Now;

            //define time range1
            DateTime startDateMorning = new DateTime(curTime.Year, curTime.Month, curTime.Day, 17, 40, 00);
            DateTime endDateMorning = new DateTime(curTime.Year, curTime.Month, curTime.Day, 17, 50, 00);

            //define time range2
            DateTime startDateEvening = new DateTime(curTime.Year, curTime.Month, curTime.Day, 10, 30, 00);
            DateTime endDateEvening = new DateTime(curTime.Year, curTime.Month, curTime.Day, 10, 40, 00);

            //time span between last update and current time in iteration
            TimeSpan span = curTime - lastUpdate;

            //check that we only monitor within interwals, and there was at least 20 minutes delay between last and current check
            if (((curTime >= startDateMorning && curTime < endDateMorning) 
                || 
                (curTime >= startDateEvening && curTime < endDateEvening)) 
                && span.Minutes > 20)
            {
                //connect to DataBase
                //get the value
                //email warning
                //other logic

                //set last uopdate as current timestamp
                lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I used `sc create Service1 start= auto binPath= "c:\Users\....\program.exe"` and trying to run it, my Service is getting stuck. So I have to look for it and terminate it manually. I assume I am not doing it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Thread.Sleep()` to avoid busy waiting or, better yet, just use a `System.Timers.Timer` (or one of its cousins) to wake up when you want. You also need to start your service in `OnStart()` instead of trying to do all its work there; that means scheduling an event handler (e.g. via `Timer`) or starting a new thread so that `OnStart()` can return on its original thread. The Windows Service system only gives a limited time for start up. `OnStop()` also needs to be implemented for graceful shutdown.

```
public partial class ServiceClassName : ServiceBase {
    private readonly Timer Ticker = new Timer {
                                               Interval = 5.0*TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute
                                                        /TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond
                                              }; // 5 minutes

    public ServiceClassName() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ticker.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Poll();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) { Ticker.Start(); }

    protected override void OnStop() { Ticker.Stop(); }

    internal static void Poll() {
        // approximate contents of your while loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"My service is getting stuck" isn't too descriptive, but you need to return from OnStart as soon as possible. You also need to respond to other service commands like OnStop, which this code can't, as it's stuck in the loop.

Run your code in a separate thread, for example using a `Task`.